# how to define an array of certain size immutable.js

Tags: typescript, immutable.js

I have this type:

```
type Route<A> = [A] | [A, A] | [A,A,A]
```

So when I define routes like this:

```
const r: Route<number> = [1,2],
     r2: Route<number> = [1,2];
```

and I put them in a set:

```
const s = new Set([r, r2]);
```

I want this to have length of 1.

To make this happen, I use Immutable.js:

```
import { List } from 'immutable';

type Route<A> = List<A>

const ir = List(1,2);
```

But now when I access this route I might get undefined at 0 index:

```
ir.get(0) // possibly undefined.
```

But I want to type check that it has at least one element up to 3 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImmutableJS does not export types that support your usecase.  You could make your own function which enforces some of the things you want via `as`, but it's not really extensible (you'd have to define new types for each size thing that you wanted).

```
import {List} from 'immutable';

type ListOfLength2<T> = Omit<List<T>, 'get'> & {
  get(idx: Exclude<number, 0 | 1>): undefined;
  get(idx: 0): T;
  get(idx: 1): T;
}

const makeListOfLength2 = <T> (val0: T, val1: T): ListOfLength2<T> => {
  return List.of(val0, val1) as ListOfLength2<T>;
}

const x = makeListOfLength2(1, 2);

const a = x.get(0) // nunber
const b = x.get(1) // number
const c = x.get(2) // undefined
```